# Why does this product not produce value of pi?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate this product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) in R but my code doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

```
W <- function(n) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        r <- (2*i/(2*i-1)*2*i/(2*i+1))
    }
    print(r*2)
}

W(10)
W(50)
pi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `r` a running product.

```
Wallis <- function(n) {
    r <- 1
    for (i in 1:n) {
        r <- r * (2*i/(2*i-1)*2*i/(2*i+1))
    }
    print(r*2)
}

Wallis(500)
#[1] 3.140024
```

Comment: My solution exactly... I just deleted mine because you did it first.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the `for`-loop and use vectorization:

```
wallis <- function(n) {
  i <- seq_len(n) 
  # Return:
  2 * prod(2 * i / (2 * i - 1) * 2 * i / (2 * i + 1))
} 

wallis(500)
#> [1] 3.140024
```

Comment: I think you forgot to write print(res) in your code. But thanks, that helps and I have given you an upvote! :)